# Sampling from a truncated random effects distribution

Tags: mixed-model, sampling, gibbs, truncation

How would one sample observations $T_{ij} = U_i + \varepsilon_{ij}$, where the distribution of $U_i, \varepsilon_{ij}$ are known and mutually independent, condition on the fact that $L_{ij} \le T_{ij} \le R_{ij}$?

I considered trying Gibbs sampling, but the resulting full conditionals don't seem to simplify. Any help appreciated!